# pgloader + docker mariadb and postgres = no connection on localhost for my databases

Tags: docker, postgresql, mariadb

I am trying to migrate from `mariaDB` to `postgres` via `pgLoader`

I have two databases running on my computer

```
mariadb on 127.0.0.1 pass:pass user:app
postgres on 127.0.0.1 pass:pass user:app
```

I run the command `pgloader mysql://app:pass@127.0.0.1/mr_dev postgresql://app:pass@127.0.0.1/mr_dev` but nothing happens. no connection in the docker logs on either mariadb and postgres; no error anywhere. the script just hangs at making the connection apparently.

but I can access them with `Sequel Pro` and `PostBird` at the same address so i know my databases are online and accessible.

so why do I receive no connection from the script ? or is pgloader not configured properly ?

```
database:
    container_name: database
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    networks:   
      app_network:
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass
      POSTGRES_USER: app
      POSTGRES_DB: mr_dev
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./volumes/database/postgres
        target: /var/lib/postgresql/data

  mariadb:
      container_name: mariadb
      image: "mariadb:${MARIADB_VERSION}"
      restart: always
      env_file: .env
      volumes:
        - "${SQL_INIT}:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
        - type: bind
          source: ${MARIADB_DATA_DIR}
          target: /var/lib/mysql
        - type: bind
          source: ${MARIADB_LOG_DIR}
          target: /var/logs/mysql
        - type: bind
          source: ${MARIADB_CERTS_DIR}
          target: /etc/certs/
        - type: bind
          source: /etc/localtime
          target: /etc/localtime:ro
        - type: bind
          source: ${MARIADB_BACKUP_DIR}
          target: /opt/mysql/backup
        - type: bind
          source: ${MARIADB_BACKUP_SCRIPT_DIR}
          target: /etc/periodic/daily
      ports:
        - "3306:3306"
      networks:
        app_network:
```